# I executed this query with error, any suggestion?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to calculate the total price of a order done by a customer:

```
SELECT 
    C.ctm_Id, O.OrderId, SUM(P.pdt_UnitPrice * O.Quantity), 
FROM 
    Customer C, Orders O, Product P
WHERE 
    P.pdt_Id = O.OrderID GROUP BY C.ctm_Id
```

Here is the error:

> *Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.*

Comment: extra comma before the FROM keyword.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard - stop using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is that you have to include all columns, which are not in an aggregate function, in the GROUP BY clause. You didn't added O.OrderId in your GROUP BY clause.

What luchosrock mentioned is the better way.

However, I strongly recommend using JOINs. By the way, you didn't put a join between Customer and Order tables either.

You want to sum the total price of an order for a customer. Your query should look like this:

```
select
    C.ctm_Id,
    O.OrderId,
    SUM(P.pdt_UnitPrice * O.Quantity)
from Customer C
join Orders O
    on C.ctm_Id = O.ctm_Id
join Product P 
    on O.pdt_Id = P.pdt_Id
group by C.ctm_Id, O.OrderId
```

Answer (score 5):

Extra comma:

```
SELECT C.ctm_Id, O.OrderId, SUM(P.pdt_UnitPrice * O.Quantity), 
                                                             ^-- here
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still got another error. Column 'Orders.OrderID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: the error message is obvious enough... you don't have a group by clause.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the coma before FROM

```
SELECT C.ctm_Id, O.OrderId, SUM(P.pdt_UnitPrice * O.Quantity) 
    FROM Customer C, Orders O, Product P
    WHERE P.pdt_Id = O.OrderID GROUP BY C.ctm_Id
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still got another error.    
Column 'Orders.OrderID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @X.YangUK As the error message clearly stated, you need to either remove the Orders.OrderID from the SELECT statement or add Orders.OrderID to your GROUP BY statement.

Answer (score 1):

`SUM(P.pdt_UnitPrice * O.Quantity),`  - extra `,`

Answer (score 1):

Try
`SELECT 
    C.ctm_Id, O.OrderId, SUM(P.pdt_UnitPrice * O.Quantity) 
FROM 
    Customer C, Orders O, Product P
WHERE 
    P.pdt_Id = O.OrderID GROUP BY C.ctm_Id,O.OrderId`